# Why we need to use Storybook in react

Tags: reactjs

Why do we need to use storybook in react? As I gone through the official doc about this I got that storybook makes **UI development interactive**.But after went to the examples on the site, I got that It used only for testing. Is it true? So for instance, If I've 4-5 components in my application so do we need to use the storybook?

Comment: Who says you need to use storybook? it's just a tool. you definitely don't need to use it if you don't want

Comment: I think if we have a bunch of components that are pure UI components (only depend on props), then storybook is a good tool to show other people how these components look like. Actually, I found storybook is the best tool for this, please comment if I there are better tools.